# CSS: resizing logo while maintaining aspect with browser

Tags: css, browser, resize, window, aspect-ratio

```
#logo {
    background: url(/images/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 268px;
    height: 96px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

This is my logo css and when I change the height and width to x% It just cuts of the bottom and right side of my logo image. How can I style my logo so that it stays at 5% of the browser width  while maintaining aspect? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your image has to be an `<img>` tag, not a background, and the CSS of this `<img>` tag :

```
#logo_img{
    width:5%;
}
```

assuming the parent of `#logo_img` is 100% in width.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `<img>` element for images, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in a background image. See [this demo at CSSplay](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/css3-background.html). [Ethan Marcotte has also detailed techniques](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/) that may fit your application.